# How do I create different txt files with different print statements?

Tags: python, file-io

I have been having a lot of trouble with this code assignment. What I am currently trying to do is create separate files for wedding invitations. What I would like to do is create a new txt file for each new printed statement/invitation. Below is what I have been trying to do, I am currently having trouble with placing each print statement in a new txt file with a new file name.

```
import os
if os.path.isfile("guest_list.txt"):
     # Open files for input
     infile = open("guest_list.txt", "r")

     line = infile.readline() # Read a line
     while line != '': # read until end-of-file
         e = open("event_details.txt","r")
         splitLine = line.split()
         letter = print("Dear,", splitLine[0],"",splitLine[1],"\n" \
                        "With great pleasure we are delighted to invite you to our wedding.\n" \
                        "We would be honored if you and your family could save the date.\n",e.read())
         w = open("wedding_invite.txt","w")
         w.write(''.join("Dear",str(splitLine[0]),"",str(splitLine[1])))
         w.write("With great pleasure we are delighted to invite you to our wedding.")
         w.write(''.join("We would be honored if you and your family could save the date.\n",e.read()))              
                        
         #read next line
         line = infile.readline() # Read next line from file
         e.close()
         w.close()
     infile.close()
```

Comment: The line starting `letter = print(...` is redundant and I think you know that is so. Please remove it.

Comment: how should the files be named? you're just writing to `wedding_invite.txt` each time, so you're only ever going to have that one file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the file `wedding_invite.txt` in each iteration.

You instead want to create a new .txt file for each guest:

```
import os
if os.path.isfile("guest_list.txt"):
    #read all the guest names into a list
    with open("guest_list.txt", "r") as infile:
        #read all the guest names to a list
        guest_list = infile.read().strip().split("\n")
    
    #read the event_details file just once instead of in each loop
    with open("event_details.txt") as infile:
        date = infile.read().strip()
    
    #loop through the guest_list and create custom invitations
    for line in guest_list:
         words = line.split(" ")
         #create new file for each guest
         with open(f"{line}.txt", "w") as outfile:
            outfile.write(f"Dear {words[0]} {words[1]},\n")
            outfile.write("With great pleasure we are delighted to invite you to our wedding.\n")
            outfile.write(f"We would be honored if you and your family could save the date.\n{date}")
```